# React Bootstrap Tab showing all content at once

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to incorporate a Tab component based off the React Bootstrap [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/#tabs-api). However, it simply shows all the content one after the other instead of only displaying the corresponding content when I navigate to a different tab. What am I missing? For reference, the code I am using is as follows:

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey='ownership' className='categories'>
      <Tab eventKey='ownership' title='Ownership'> <Ownership /> </Tab>

      <Tab eventKey='profile' title='Energy'> <Energy /> </Tab>
      <Tab eventKey='service' title='Service'> <Service /> </Tab>
      <Tab eventKey='behuman' title='Be Human'> <Human /> </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

where Ownership, Energy, Service, & Human are components/classes that are meant to be the content, much like the original documentation's use of Sonnet.

Comment: Can you post a screen cap of what it is displaying?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to install [vanilla Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/#npm) and import required stylesheets.

> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap,
>   we don't ship with any included css. However, some stylesheet is
>   required to use these components.

**1. Install Bootstrap:**

```
npm install bootstrap
```

or

```
yarn add bootstrap
```

**2. Import styles:**

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

---

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Tab from "react-bootstrap/Tab";
import Tabs from "react-bootstrap/Tabs";
import Ownership from "./components/Ownership";
import Energy from "./components/Energy";
import Service from "./components/Service";
import BeHuman from "./components/BeHuman";

export default function App() {
    return (
        <Tabs defaultActiveKey="ownership" className="categories m-3">
            <Tab eventKey="ownership" title="Ownership">
                <Ownership />
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey="profile" title="Energy">
                <Energy />
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey="service" title="Service">
                <Service />
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey="behuman" title="Be Human">
                <BeHuman />
            </Tab>
        </Tabs>
    );
}
```

Here is a basic [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-sinoussi-den7z) based on your code.